# Entering 'm' terminates the program?

Tags: c++

Entering `(x)m` e.g `200m` was working fine until a later revision (I do not remember what I changed) and now entering `m` at all will terminate the whole program.

Everything else works such as `23cm` and `39ft`.

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    // Prompts Input
    cout << "Enter a double value followed by a unit (cm, m, in, ft): ";

    // Variables
    bool first {true};
    double input {0.0};
    double smallest {0.0};
    double largest {0.0};
    string unit {};
    
    // Check Input
    while(cin >> input >> unit)
    {
        // Convert unit to m
        if (unit == "cm")
        {
            input /= 100;
            unit = "m";
        }
        else if (unit == "in")
        {
            input /= 39.37;
            unit = "m";
        }
        else if (unit == "ft")
        {
            input /= 3.281;
            unit = "m";
        }
        else if (unit == "m")
        {
            unit = "m";
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        // Print input and unit
        cout << input << unit << "\n";

        // Main Loop
        if(first == true) 
        {
            first = false;
            smallest = input;
            largest = input;
            cout << input << unit << " is the first value therefore is the smallest and largest so far. \n";
        }
        else if(input > largest)
        {
            cout << input << unit << " is the largest so far. \n";
            largest = input;
        }
        else if (input < smallest)
        { 
            cout << input << unit << " is the smallest so far. \n";
            smallest = input;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << input << unit << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner, please forgive me if my code is formatted badly thank you

Comment: What is `../../std_lib_facilities.h`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should learn how to debug and find out the root cause. It's expecting number but you are entering a character which is breaking that loop

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry, I do not know the clear answer to that, but in all the example in Programming Principles and Practice with c++ all contain this as the header, and i had to download it from the website

Comment: @Asesh isn't it expecting a number and a unit? when i enter `38 cm` or `38cm` it works just fine, but somehow `m` breaks it

Comment: I guess that header equals to `using namespace std` in this case.

Comment: @LouisGo yes it does :) is that the reason? the book i am using always uses it

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YmSkQXeecqAh20Nr).

Comment: If you do not know why you include a header then don't and try to understand the errors you then get. If no errors, celebrate.

Comment: @MikeCAT really? did you make any changes

Comment: @SILO, Does the problem occur for values like `200m` or only `m`?

Comment: @SILO Just changed `#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"` to standard things.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry, usually i wouldn't add a header if it's not needed but in my textbook it states to always use it until I reach a certain chapter. I will remove it now, thank you!

Comment: "was working fine until a later revision (I do not remember what I changed)" start using a version management system. E.g. git, or mercurial. Or folder-copying.

Comment: @kuro both unfortunately

Comment: Sorry "always use it until I reach a certain chapter" actually makes sense. I guess they want to introduce you cleanly to things. Do that. But only as long as you follow that book. (Cheers for using a book. Good idea.)

Comment: @Yunnosch its okay! thank you for helping though :D

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by not including `std_lib_facilities.h` as suggested by my textbook, thank you @MikeCat for the answer!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062354/mikecat

Instead, I included `iostream`:

`#include <iostream>`

Which fixed the problem

Comment: Instead, I included `iostream`

Comment: :-) Nice edit. Have fun with your new privilege.